# Adding to variables from inside and outside of methods

Tags: ruby

I created a shooting game, and for every person killed the user gains five points and one kill. The points are added to an instance variable and the instance variable is inside a defined method like so:

```
def method
  @kills = 0
  @points = 0

  puts "You shoot a bad guy!"
  @kills += 1
  @points += 5
  method
end
```

Why is it that when the instance variable is inside the method it repeats the method and doesn't add to the instance variable it just repeats the method and restarts the variable at 0.

But when the instance variable is outside the method it will add to the instance variable and repeat the method like so:

```
   @kills = 0
   @points = 0

   def method
     puts "You shoot a bad guy!"
     @kills += 1
     @points += 5
   end
```

The game I created already works, I'm asking why does it have to be outside of the definition to add to the variable.

Comment: Alright, let's see how much better you will be received after vandalizing your post.

Comment: Go for it, already been done genius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, you've embedded the method's name inside the method, which isn't going to give you the result you want. You've created a recursive method, which isn't going to exit.

```
def method
  [...]
  method
end
```

In the second you've removed that new invocation, which will allow the method to exit correctly.

The basics of an OO-script in Ruby is something like:

```
class Foo

  def initialize
    @var = 0
  end

  def var
    @var
  end

  def increment_var(n=1)
    @var += n
  end

  def decrement_var(n=1)
    @var -= n
  end
end
```

Where we can use the Foo class to create a new instance of the class called `foo`:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.class # => Foo
```

We can look at the current value of `@var`:

```
foo.var # => 0
```

Calling `increment_var` without a parameter defaults to 1:

```
foo.increment_var # => 1
```

Calling `increment_var` with 2:

```
foo.increment_var(2) # => 3
foo.var # => 3
```

The same is true for calling `foo.decrement_var`:

```
foo.decrement_var # => 2
foo.decrement_var(2) # => 0
foo.var # => 0
```

We use an `initialize` method to define the state of the object when it's instantiated by calling `new` on the class.

Comment: This is by far the most detailed answer I have ever gotten on SO you defiantly deserve some recognition thank you.

Comment: This ain't nothing. You should see my detailed answers.

Answer (score 0):

Put the initialization of the instance variables in an initialization method like so:

```
def initialize:
    @kills = 0
    @points = 0
end
```

The initialize method is called when you create a new instance of the class.  Each time you call `o.method()` the instance variables will be changed as you expect.